# How to run multiple task in Telethon Python

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telethon

I have issue about run multiple function using Telethon
for example I want to using bot management command and tracker function both same time so I know I should multithread but here is my script I am trying to run both of them but never run at the same time.

```
def Checker():
    print('I am Running')
    while True:
        if isStart:
            for i in SpesificDictionary:
                Element = SpesificDictionary[i]
                poster(Element,i)
        time.sleep(10)

async def poster(Element,chatId): 
    text = Element.API.getText()   
    if text != None:
        luckyNews = await randomAds()
        if(luckyNews != None):
            print(f"Sending to {luckyNews[0]} with {luckyNews[1]}")
            text += f"\n\n <b> Ad's:</b> '<a href='{luckyNews[0]}'><b>{luckyNews[1]}</b></a>'"
        else:
            text += f"\n\n <b> Ad's:</b> <b>Ads your project</b>"
        
        if(len(SpesificButtonAdvertise) != 0):
            keyboard = [[Button.url(str(SpesificButtonAdvertise[1]),str(SpesificButtonAdvertise[0]))]]
        else:
            keyboard = [[Button.url('Advertise your project here ', "https://t.me/contractchecker")]]

        
        # chat = BOT.get_entity(-1001639775918)  #-1001639775918 test       # main -1001799563725  # sohbet : -1001648583714

        chat = BOT.get_entity(chatId) 
        await BOT.send_file(chat, 'giphy.gif', caption= text, buttons= keyboard, parse_mode = 'HTML')
    else:
        print("Waiting for the next update")


def main():
    BOT.start(bot_token=BOT_TOKEN)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [loop.create_task(Checker()),
             loop.create_task(BOT.run_until_disconnected())]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    loop.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with the listed code.

Your `def Checker()` is not an `async def`. It's going to run immediately when you call it, and `loop.create_task(Checker())` won't work at all.

You are calling `poster`, which is an `async def`, without using `await`. This means it won't run at all.

You are using `time.sleep`, which blocks the entire thread, meaning `asyncio` cannot run its loop, and therefore any tasks created won't run either.

`BOT.get_entity` is also an `async def`. It should be `await`-ed.

Checker would look like this:

```py
async def Checker():
    print('I am Running')
    while True:
        if isStart:
            for i in SpesificDictionary:
                Element = SpesificDictionary[i]
                await poster(Element,i)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

And don't forget to `await BOT.get_entity(chatId)`.

---

But I strongly recommend reading through the [`asyncio` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) and being more comfortable with `asyncio` before attempting to write more complex code.